# I want to go to grad school for probability theory related stuff, but i do not want to get a B.S in math? Can I circumvent this?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process, career-development

I'm graduating this fall semester but I recently fell in love with probability. I have taken non-proof math probability(Sheldon Ross book), math statistics, and stochastic processes. I want to continue taking these courses, but there are none left as an undergrad. I tried taking some actuary courses ( Interest Theory, Contingent models) thinking that they would be just as fun as the "pure" mathematics courses but I had to drop those classes because they were too damn boring. I have done pretty well in my math minor classes, but I don't think I have an inclination for proofs meaning that I don't have any interest in taking math major proof intensive courses to get a B.S in math. The only proof courses I would like to take would be those directly related to probability theory. Is there any way I can go to grad school for Mathematics for Probability without actually having a B.S in math? Should I just man up and take the proof based courses? Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Of course it's possible to attend grad school in mathematics without a bachelor's in mathematics, but virtually all grad school mathematics is heavily proof-based and it will be assumed that you are already very comfortable with proofs from your undergraduate work, so you will need this background.

Comment: If, as it sounds, your interest is driven by applications, I would suggest studying one of the (many) relevant applied branches.  Finance, Mathematical Biology, etc.  Worth pointing out, though, that many of the most interesting applications are subtle and will require a real understanding of the techniques and that inevitvably requires proofs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some bad news: graduate work in probability theory is extremely heavy in proofs, and unless you can get used to working with them, they will be a wall that will block your progress in graduate school.

In order to make probability theory rigorous, you really need to know about measure theory, which genuinely requires you to be fluent in basic concepts in real analysis. Additionally, basic proof tactics remain relevant and important.

I would regard it as a basic truism that if you can't force yourself to complete a BS in Mathematics, there is virtually no way that you will be able to complete a graduate degree in probability. You may be able to find a home in applied mathematics or something like that, particularly if you've mastered a cognate science field like physics or biology, but what you will be studying will not quite be "probability theory" in that case. And even in that case, not being comfortable with proofs will be a serious stumbling block in many, though not all, degree programs with the word "math" in them.